# Error showing unknown name in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-6

wen i select an option from drop down box, onchange functionality is called which has
the functin
**retrieveurl(url,formbean); code written.**

It calls the ajax written in javascript and its not able to detect my version of browser i.e IE6.0.2900....

below code i have used...

```
try {

  req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

} catch (e) {

   try {

      req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

   } catch {

       alert('second catch');
   }

}
```

wen i debug it comes to the second catch alert

can anyone help me on this??

Comment: couldn't that has to do with IE security parameters about activeX?

Answer (score 1):

Missed catch**(e)** in second catch-statement

```
try
{
    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}

catch(e)
{
    try
    {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    catch(e)
    {
        alert('second catch');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
I would also suggest to use ALL version of MS XML HTTP object

```
function getHTTPRequest () 
{
    var xmlHttp;
    try 
    {
        // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE 8
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {
        // IE and possible XML HTTP ProIDs
        var XmlHttpVersions = new Array(
                            "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.7.0",
                            "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0",
                            "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0",
                            "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHTTP",
                            "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"
                            );
        for (var i=0; i<XmlHttpVersions.length && !xmlHttp; i++) 
        {
            try 
            {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject(XmlHttpVersions[i]);
            }
            catch(err) {} //Ignore


        }        
    }

    if(!xmlHttp) 
    {
        alert("No HttpRequest supported");
    }
    else 
    {
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}

var xhr = getHTTPRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this should work on IE6. But you are missing a (e) argument in the second catch, which probably should be there. Maybe this is messing things up? Sorry I can't check, no IE6.